# Auto-increment [id] field in a table in an SQL-Server database

Tags: sql-server, insert, auto-increment, identity

I have different tables, containing an `id` field. That field is typically defined as `id (PK, int, not null)`.

Normally, when adding an entry to a table, I add the value of the `id` field myself, but I'm wondering if there's no automatic way to do that:

The following is not working: (there already is an entry with `id` being 1)

```
INSERT [dbo].[Settings] ([GroupId], [Value],    [Name], [Id],  [Description], [Admin])
       VALUES           (        1,    N'1', N'BLABLA',    1, N'meer blabla',       0)
```

The following is also not working (the `id` field not being filled in):

```
INSERT [dbo].[Settings] ([GroupId], [Value],    [Name], [Description], [Admin]) 
       VALUES           (        1,    N'1', N'BLABLA', N'meer blabla',      0)
```

I know about the possibility to add a kind of `IDENTITY` table, which might handle this, but I'm very reluctant to add another table to the customer's database.

Does anybody know a way to get this done? If possible, I would like to have two possibilities:

- Finding the first possible id (using holes in the existing ids, if any): imagine that I have the following list of existing ids: (1, 2, 3, 4, 11, 12, 13, 14). Then I want 5 to be the next one.
- Finding the highest id plus one: imagine that I have the following list of existing ids: (1, 2, 3, 4, 11, 12, 13, 14). Then I want 15 to be the next one.

Does anybody know how to get this done in a one-liner SQL command, without altering the customer's database?

For your information, I'm using Telerik OpenAccess for creating and accessing the database, and one of the items I can see is this:

```
configuration.HasProperty(o => o.Id).IsIdentity();
```

However, for that table, I don't see that in SQL-Server:

[image: SQL-Server screenshot]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not exactly sure what your end goal is here, as your Post kind of asks about 3 different things. It is possible to make the `ID` field an auto-increment without adding another table, but do you want to do it on a table that already has data in it or an empty table?

Comment: Not another table, just create a column with the `IDENTITY` property. Unfortunately youo can't add it to an existing column, you need to drop and recreate the column or the whole table.

Comment: @J.D.: thanks for your quick reply. I already have a table, which contains an `id` field, and I'm creating SQL `INSERT INTO` queries in order to add more data to that table (there already are data present in that table).

Comment: @Charlieface: I prefer not to modify the structure of the database, so I would prefer not to add another column to the table.

Comment: Like I said: it's just a property of the column, so you can recreate the table with the same definition, just add `IDENTITY` to that column.

Comment: @Charlieface: sorry for my too quick remark. You might be on to something, but what I see in source code and in SQL-Server does not seem to match, as you can see in my edit.

Comment: Can't help you there, I suggest you contact Telerik support. Was the database already created when you added that `IsIdentity`? If so did you create a migration? Are you sure it doesn't work if you recreate the whole database?

Comment: Alternatively to get auto generating numbers you can use Create Sequence - see Books on Line

Answer (score 1):

Typically the best way to get this done if you have to preserve the values in the id column and **not** manually insert the id is -

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Settings_x
(
    GroupId INT               --or whatever datatype
  , value NVARCHAR(256)       --or whatever datatype
  , Name NVARCHAR(256)        --or whatever datatype
  , Id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1)
  , Description NVARCHAR(256) --or whatever datatype
  , Admin BIT                 --or whatever datatype
  , CONSTRAINT PK_Settings_x
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Id)
);

SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Settings_x ON;
INSERT INTO dbo.Settings_x
(
    GroupId
  , value
  , Name
  , Id
  , Description
  , Admin
)
SELECT GroupId
     , value
     , Name
     , Id
     , Description
     , Admin
FROM dbo.Settings;
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Settings_x OFF;

EXEC sys.sp_rename @objname = N'dbo.Settings'  -- nvarchar(1035)
                 , @newname = N'Settings_old'; -- sysname
EXEC sys.sp_rename @objname = N'dbo.Settings_x' -- nvarchar(1035)
                 , @newname = N'dbo.Settings';  -- sysname
EXEC sys.sp_rename @objname = N'dbo.<youroldpkname>'   -- nvarchar(1035)
                 , @newname = N'<youroldpkname>_old'; -- sysname
EXEC sys.sp_rename @objname = N'dbo.PK_Settings_x'   -- nvarchar(1035)
                 , @newname = N'PK_Settings'; -- sysname
```

That will create a new table with the identity property of *true* on the id column, insert all of the current records with their existing id value, and then rename the current table and pk name to Settings_old and rename the new table and pk name to Settings.

With that, you could just run the second insert statement you tried running and be fine.

```
INSERT dbo.Settings
(
    GroupId
  , Value
  , Name
  , Description
  , Admin
)
VALUES
(1, N'1', N'BLABLA', N'meer blabla', 0)
```

If you wanted to just dynamically find the lowest available missing id in your id column, you could run this -

```
SELECT TOP 1
       gaps.prevID + 1 AS id
FROM
(
    SELECT id
         , LAG(id, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY id) AS prevID
    FROM dbo.Settings
) gaps
WHERE gaps.id - gaps.prevID > 1
```

and if you wanted to use that as part of your first insert statement, you could run this -

```
INSERT dbo.Settings
(
    GroupId
  , Value
  , Name
  , Id
  , Description
  , Admin
)
SELECT _row.GroupId
     , _row.Value
     , _row.Name
     , new_id.id
     , _row.Description
     , _row.Admin
FROM
(
    VALUES
        (1, N'1', N'BLABLA', N'meer blabla', 0)
) _row (GroupId, Value, Name, Description, Admin)
    CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT TOP 1
           ids.id
    FROM
    (
        SELECT gaps.prevID + 1 AS id
        FROM
        (
            SELECT Id
                 , LAG(Id, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY Id) AS prevID
            FROM dbo.Settings
        ) gaps
        WHERE gaps.Id - gaps.prevID > 1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT MAX(Id) + 1 AS id
        FROM dbo.Settings
    ) ids
    ORDER BY id ASC
) AS new_id;
```

That would dynamically find the lowest unused id value and use it in your insert statement. If there were no gaps in your table, it would return the next id you could use.

Hope that helps. Feel free to ask any followup.